# undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new

    end

    def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            flash[:success] ="You have successfully logged in"
            redirect_to users_path(user)

        else
            flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid email or password"
            render 'new'

        end

    end

    def destroy
        session[:user_id] = nil
        flash[:success] = "Successfully logged out"
        redirect_to root_path   

    end
end
```

[This is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDBJ.png)
[image: This is my error]

here is the routes.rb

```
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new'

post 'login', to: 'sessions#create'

delete 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

Comment: Can you try changing `:session` to :sessions` and let me know if it works?

Comment: thanks for the reply..but it says "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your error message: params[:session][:email].downcase is nil. According to your params, it should be:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:username].downcase)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here.

One is that `:session` should be converted to `:sessions`.

If that doesn't solve it, try implementing strong parameters.

Basically, `User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email]` returns nil, because it can't find a user with these attributes.

The solution is to use `strong parameters`, so Active Record finds them

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Under your `private` section, you can define parameters

```
private

  def person_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
```

The reason you need this is due to Rails Security

> With strong parameters, Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted. This means that you'll have to make a conscious decision about which attributes to allow for mass update. This is a better security practice to help prevent accidentally allowing users to update sensitive model attributes.

Add the strong params code above to your controller and it should fix your problem.